# Find latest Ubuntu 20.04 AMI-ID to launch a simple micro instance using AWS-CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I don't have existing AMIs in my account.

I'd like to have a shell command sequence to launch a simple t2.micro instance using AWS CLI. Currently I have:

```sh
# region = eu-west-3 region in ~/.aws/config

aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name test > test.kp.json
# OK

aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name test --description test > test.sg.json
# OK

QUERY=ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-*20.04*-amd64*
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=$QUERY" --query "reverse(sort_by(Images, &CreationDate))[0].[ImageId,Name]" --output text
# ami-03dd7c8a173e735c0   ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20210430-84dfee58-b88e-45ac-b133-db810fba9d60

aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-03dd7c8a173e735c0 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name test --security-group-ids test
# An error occurred (OptInRequired) when calling the RunInstances operation: In order to use this AWS Marketplace product you need to accept terms and subscribe. To do so please visit https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=7v6zoqj7fqa0yxobp2glr6kps
```

But this opt-in page leads to some unrelated `Latent AI Platform (LAP)` product, not Ubuntu.

What am I doing wrong? How to spin the simplest Ubuntu instance?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking to launch a normal Ubuntu @ eu-west-3

Comment: Do you want to get the latest Ubuntu AMI programmatically without hard coding?

Comment: try `aws ec2 describe-images --region eu-west-3 ...` - does that fix anything?

Comment: EBS or instance?

Comment: I've found via the console `ami-0f7cd40eac2214b37   ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20210430`

`QUERY=ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20210430` finds it correctly, but `QUERY=ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-*20.04*-amd64*` finds something else `ami-03dd7c8a173e735c0   ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20210430-84dfee58-b88e-45ac-b133-db810fba9d60`

Comment: I think aws `ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-*20.04*-amd64*" --query "reverse(sort_by(Images, &CreationDate))[0].[ImageId,Name]" --output text` is not enough to find the correct one

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have a programmatic method for finding the latest Ubuntu versions from terminal without going to the browser

Comment: `ami-0f7cd40eac2214b37` is also not found at https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

Comment: `ami-03dd7c8a173e735c0` is a valid Ubuntu image - maybe it's a mishap in the CLI, can you retry please?

Comment: If it doesn't, specify `ami-04c512eb02ad15697` - does that work?

Comment: Yes, it works too. But it should be easily findable via describe-images.

Comment: There is no easy Console catalog of all AMIs with filtering either

Comment: "works too" - both work?

Comment: Both `ami-04c512eb02ad15697` and `ami-0f7cd40eac2214b37` work. The one found with `ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-*20.04*-amd64*" --query "reverse(sort_by(Images, &CreationDate))[0].[ImageId,Name]" --output text` does not work

Comment: Also I cannot `ssh` into these running instances. Do I need to create security group differently?

Comment: You need to open up port 22 on the incoming rules of the security group yes

Comment: Ahh, me back onto google :)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html :)

Comment: It worked, thank you! I guess the question about mysterious AMIs is still standing...